# Number Aligning Algorithm

Tags: math

Is there an algorithm that will take two columns of numbers and determine if they have a value in common?

Two columns:

One increases by .3 with each value.  The other increases erratically.  I want to determine if the two columns have a value in common.

```
.3  .1
.6  .2
.9  .4
1.2  .5
1.5  .9
1.8  .13
```

Comment: Yes, there is such an algorithm.

Comment: Does the first always start at 0.3?

Comment: The initial value of each changes depending on the input.

Comment: 0.9 + 0.3 != 0.12 - did you mean something else for the first column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both series are *increasing* (or sorted<sup>1</sup> in general), there is an `O(n)` solution. You can't do any better than that, because you need to look at every element in the erratically-increasing list *at least once* in the worst case.

Simply traverse both at the same time in a zipper-like fashion: Always get the next element from the list, that currently has a smaller element than the other one.

```
> .3   .1 < | > .3   .1   | > .3   .1   |   .3   .1   |   .3   .1   |   .3   .1   
  .6   .2   |   .6   .2 < |   .6   .2   | > .6   .2   | > .6   .2   | > .6   .2   
  .9   .4   |   .9   .4   |   .9   .4 < |   .9   .4 < |   .9   .4   |   .9   .4   
  .12  .5   |   .12  .5   |   .12  .5   |   .12  .5   |   .12  .5 < |   .12  .5   
  .15  .9   |   .15  .9   |   .15  .9   |   .15  .9   |   .15  .9   |   .15  .9 < 
  .18  .13  |   .18  .13  |   .18  .13  |   .18  .13  |   .18  .13  |   .18  .13
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Where sorted means with respect to a [total order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order).

Comment: Since once of your list is steadily increasing by `0.3`, you may be able to skip ahead several numbers at once when the erratically-increasing list currently holds the bigger element. But apart from that, I don't think there is anything you can do. You still won't be any faster than `O(n)` though.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll have to work on the set more then.  I really want that O(log(n)).

Comment: @PrincePeregrine That won't work. You will need to look at *every* element of the erratically-increasing list in the worst case.

Comment: Yeah, what I meant by work on the set was try to alter it to get a better set that I can come up with an O(log(n)) algorithm.  I hear ya for things as they are.

Comment: @PrincePeregrine Assuming you are talking about constructing your list of numbers, you can ask a new question for that. Keep in mind, that whenever you just have a bunch of data that you need to process into some form, keeping all of them, the runtime is usually at least `O(n)`. Have you made sure this is even a performance problem for you?

Comment: I knew I could do it in O(n), but I wanted to know if there was an O(log(n)) solution.  The number of elements can grow to 2**500+, and 'zippering' through that many elements, though O(n), would take much longer than I want.

Comment: @PrincePeregrine 2^500? Are you sure? I suggest you create a new question and explain your problem in more detail. In this question, you have already presented some solution to your *real* problem and wanted to know, how to make that *particular* solution faster. If we know what you're actually trying to do, someone may come up with a better solution.

Comment: Yeah I am sure about that.  I'll try to come up with a better way to ask. Thanks.